# Awaiting two different async tasks in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to write a WPF application in which:

- data may be received asynchronously at any time over the network, and
- data may be sent asynchronously, but execution must not continue until a particular request is received.

A typical execution sequence may be as follows:

1. I receive an initial greeting from the server, asynchronously.
2. I send a request beginning with "01".
3. I wait until I receive a response beginning with "01".
4. I then send a request beginning with "02".
5. I wait until I receive a response beginning with "02".
6. ...

I effectively need to await two things concurrently. I have to keep receiving data from the network, while at the same time not letting the send task complete until the receiving task allows it to. To do the latter, I'm using a TaskCompletionSource, which I then expect to use to [SetResult()](https://www.google.com.mt/search?q=taskcompletionsource%20setresult&oq=taskcompletionsource%20setres&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.3101j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) and thus complete the sending task.

However, I am finding that this approach results in deadlocks. Once the sending task is awaiting the TaskCompletionSource, the receiving task stops... receiving data.

How can I handle this scenario and have two separate tasks awaiting at the same time, such that one may eventually allow the other to complete?

Comment: I recommend you consider [reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) for this kind of scenario. It *can* be done using `async`, but Rx will probably be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Can you show some code? How would you do it synchronously?